# Equivalent of "tabulate" and "C"of R in python

Tags: python, r, numpy, tabulate

I am currently working on transferring code available in R to python. In R, there is a function called [tabulate](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/tabulate#:%7E:text=tabulate%20is%20the%20workhorse%20for,integer%20.) and [C](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/c).

Is there is any function available in python that is equivalent to `tabulate` and `C` function of R?

Comment: Take a look at the first free chapter here: https://www.datacamp.com/courses/python-for-r-users it will answer your first question, which if you couldn't answer yourself, I really recommend doing a basic python tutorial before continuing. This chapter seems like an ok place to start.

Comment: Regarding `tabulate`, take a look at numpy's [`bincount`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html#numpy.bincount)

Answer (score 2):

From the docs for [`c`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/c) it is used to

> Combine Values into a Vector or List

In python you can combine values into a list using brackets so `c(1, 2, 3)` in R become `[1, 2, 3]` in Python. But if you didn't know this, I really urge you to stop porting the code and take two days to go through a basic Python tutorial. Understanding lists in Python is about as basic as you get.

The docs for [`tabulate`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/tabulate#:%7E:text=tabulate%20is%20the%20workhorse%20for,integer%20.) state

> `tabulate` takes the integer-valued vector `bin` and counts the number of times each integer occurs in it.

this sounds just like numpy's [`bincount`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html#numpy.bincount)

> Count number of occurrences of each value in array of non-negative ints.

unless you have a requirement to also count negative ints? If not, it's pretty much a drop in replacement. So `tabulate(c(2,3,3,5), nbins = 10)` becomes `np.bincount(np.array([2, 3, 3, 5]), minlength=10)`